# Enable a PersonAccount in DeveloperEdition

Tags: person-accounts

I want to enable a PersonAcount in my new DeveloperEdition,then i move to contact support for to put the case.But the case page is not opened for my DeveloperEdition.Is there any other way to put a case in contact support....

### Regards

Venkatesh R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create the case to have PersonAccounts enabled from the Help link in the top right of Salesforce. It will appear between your name and the App drop down.

Then Open a Case by first pressing Contact Support.
[image: Creating a Support Case]

I think you want the set:

- **I need assistance with** CRM
- **Product Topics** Limits & Feature Activations

Last time I did this I made some additional notes about the requirements:
[Salesforce requirements for enabling Person Accounts in an Org.](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/05/salesforce-requirements-for-enabling.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel....i click on the open a case but it redirects to https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1 Contact home page....It is possible to open a case in new developer edition?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Stops Supporting for Developer Editions..any how you can try to send direct mail to "support@salesforce.com" from Salesforce registered email with DevOrg ID..

Try your luck :D

Comment: Thanks for your comment Setty...I already send email to support@salesforce.com but their reply is go to contactsupport in your developer org.....and put a case....